# Want to use two DataSource in spring boot Application(mysql,h2 database)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i want to use two data source in spring boot app like for some table i want to use h2 and for some use mysql using jpa hibernate.
in my application.java what i m doing is..

```
 @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.primary")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        System.out.println(list+"============");
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.secondary")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }


     @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
        @Primary
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean primaryEntityManagerFactory(
                EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
            return builder
                    .dataSource(primaryDataSource())
                    .packages("com.opallios.ode.model")
                    .persistenceUnit("primary")
                    .properties(buildProperties())
                    .build();
        }


     @Bean(name = "secondaryEntityManagerFactory")
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean secondaryEntityManagerFactory(
                EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
            return builder
                    .dataSource(secondaryDataSource())
                    .packages("com.opallios.ode.model")
                    .persistenceUnit("secondary")
                    .properties(buildProperties())
                    .build();
        }

        private Map<String, Object> buildProperties() {
            // This is usually set by HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
            Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            properties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy",
                    ImprovedNamingStrategy.class.getName());
            return properties;
        }

        @Bean
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("secondaryEntityManagerFactory")
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
            JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
            txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
            return txManager;
        }

        @Bean
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory")
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerr(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
            JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
            txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
            return txManager;
        } 


    @Bean   
    public ServletRegistrationBean h2servletRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new WebServlet());
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
        params.put("webAllowOthers", h2WebAllow);
        registration.setInitParameters(params);
        registration.addUrlMappings("/console/*");
        return registration;
    }enter code here
```

its giving exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain

i want all suggestions if any i want  a simpel code in which mysql as well as h2 db can be configured and can fetch data from db .

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this ? I got same configuration, when I run Spring-boot application it works awesome with mysql but when I try to run Integration test with H2, primary datasource work but secondary doesn't. If I change Integration test to use Mysql then it both datasource works and test cases.